# Fast way to switch bits order?

Tags: java, c, go, byte, endianness

I have a binary like this

```
10011011
```

My data store like this `10,01,10,11`, but I want to reorder like this

```
11100110
```

The data look like `11,10,01,10`.This operation same as ByteOrder convert but in bits level.

Any fast bitop way to do this ?

Currently, I have to decode this to four int then merge to one.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? And also it is time to actually decide what language do you need java, c or go? Or do you think people will write you in 3 languages?

Comment: There only byte or byte-order is relate to this question, I hope more people can see this, so I tagged the language that I know.

Comment: I do not think that this is a correct way to draw attention (yes it worked right now), but tagging a question with `c`, `c++`, `python`, `php`, `javascript`, `haskel`, `ruby`, `java`, `objective-c` just to draw attention is not really nice.

Comment: The proper solution is to use a nibble-based lookup table. Anyway, not going to answer this since I don't know all 3 languages...

Comment: @wener, observing that rude behaviour "work[ed] for [you]" does not justify it! It just shows you don't care about other peoples time/effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way *might* be to precompute a table of all the values:

```
final int[] values = new int[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    values[i] = (i & 0b1100_0000) >> 6
                | (i & 0b0011_0000) >> 2
                | (i & 0b0000_1100) << 2
                | (i & 0b0000_0011) << 6;
}
```

and then use array lookups rather than bit manipulation.

Naturally, you'll want to profile.

Comment: I mark you as answer, because this way is fast enough !

Comment: Alternatively you'd make the lookup-table nibble based, so it won't consume as much memory. It should be `const` and initialized, not set in run-time.

Comment: @Lundin: Java doesn't have a `const` keyword; and my example didn't show it being set in run-time, specifically, but rather, simply showed the code to generate/populate the array. As for nibble-based lookups -- I'm not sure. As I said in my answer, the OP should profile. It's possible that the bit-twiddling will actually be faster than the array lookup.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using bitmasks and bitshift in one step without breaking it into 4 different variables:

**Go solution** (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/C_BdleF8PJ)):

```
i := 0x9b // 10011011
fmt.Printf("%b\n", i)

i = (i&0x03)<<6 | (i&0x0c)<<2 | (i&0x30)>>2 | (i&0xc0)>>6
fmt.Printf("%b\n", i)
```

Output:

```
10011011
11100110
```

**In Java:**

```
int i = 0x9b; // 10011011
System.out.printf("%x\n", i);

i = (i & 0x03) << 6 | (i & 0x0c) << 2 | (i & 0x30) >> 2 | (i & 0xc0) >> 6;
System.out.printf("%x\n", i);
```

Output (it is hex, but represents the same numbers):

```
9b
e6
```

Since each bit-group (group of 2 bits) has to be moved from its original place in the input, I don't think you can do it in fewer steps (steps as masking and shifting). If this is not fast enough for you, your only option to make it faster is to pre-compute the transformation and store the results in an array as detailed in @ruakh's answer. Of course this becomes unfeasible if we allow more than just 8 bits.

Comment: I code in this way, but is there any easy way to not split up and merge ?